# When I'm going to install NumPy to my PyCharm IDE, then it occur this error

Tags: python, numpy, installation, pip, pycharm

**My PyCharm projects PATH is** :- D:\PycharmProjects

You can look at the error down below. This error is not a pip error. I can't understand what it says. I tried it so much that I can I saw the video about this but this error not solve its only appear when I'm going to install NumPy in PyCharm terminal if I install it from cmd it install successfully.

rror is:

```
(venv) PS D:\\PycharmProjects\> pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
Downloading numpy-1.26.4.tar.gz (15.8 MB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 15.8/15.8 MB 5.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Installing backend dependencies ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─\> \[36 lines of output\]
Collecting ninja\>=1.8.2
Using cached ninja-1.11.1.1.tar.gz (132 kB)
Installing build dependenci`your text`es: started
Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
Getting requirements to build wheel: started
Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Building wheels for collected packages: ninja
Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml): started
Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

            Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
            exit code: 1
    
            [13 lines of output]
            C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cay87x7e\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-     packages\setuptools_scm\git.py:308: UserWarning: git archive did not support describe output
          warnings.warn("git archive did not support describe output")
        C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cay87x7e\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools_scm\git.py:327: UserWarning: unprocessed git archival found (no export subst applied)
          warnings.warn("unprocessed git archival found (no export subst applied)")
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cay87x7e\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\skbuild\setuptools_wrap.py", line 645, in setup
            cmkr = cmaker.CMaker(cmake_executable)
          File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cay87x7e\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\skbuild\cmaker.py", line 148, in __init__
            self.cmake_version = get_cmake_version(self.cmake_executable)
          File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cay87x7e\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\skbuild\cmaker.py", line 105, in get_cmake_version
            raise SKBuildError(msg) from err
    
        Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is cmake
        [end of output]
    
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for ninja
      Failed to build ninja
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for ninja, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
      [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─\> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

I tried from you tube videos and google it then i cannot solve it
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand you should reinstall python ide files of latest version and pycharm. You can also shift to vs code which is famous amongst programmers using python and such languages. It has occurred because there is a missing file in the system which is causing the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As the error log indicates, your issue originates not from pip but from CMake. You should double-check your CMake installation in case you have it installed. If not, you can download the latest release from here: https://cmake.org/download/